# How to upgrade to Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: 14.04, updates, 15.10

Ubuntu 15.10 was released yesterday. What's the proper way to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 2):

The only proper way of upgrading without doing a fresh install is to do it in sequences. So you should first go for 14.10 then 15.04 and finally 15.10.

The procedure is quite similar to this, you only need to do the "do-release-upgrade -d" one more time : [Update Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/618741/update-ubuntu-14-04-to-15-04)