# Tried to upgrade from 14.04 to 15.10, accidentally upgraded to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 15.10, 16.04

There is no desktop, and none of the solutions I'm finding online seem to work. ('sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop', they all have dependencies which can't be installed)

I'd like to "roll-back" to 15.10 if that is even possible, at this point, I'd even take 14.04 back.

Any help being pointed in the right direction would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is twofold - how (or if) you can downgrade from 16.04 to 15.10/14.02, and how to upgrade correctly to 15.10.

Downgrading is possible, but a tedious and risky process, with no guarantee of restoring your system as it was. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version/%22this%20link%20for%20more%20details.%22) for more details.

If you want to upgrade (after the downgrading) to 15.10, it can't be done directly, according to [the answers here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688820/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-15-10) You have to upgrade to every release in between, to 14.10, 15.04, and finally 15.10.

I recommend simply removing your new 16.04, and installing 15.10. Recently, I asked how to upgrade from 15.10 to 16.04, and I was advised to do a clean install. That is only one release apart.

So even though a clean install is quite a process, it seems to me it's less of a hassle than downgrading and upgrading in baby steps. Just remember to back up all of your user files, before you start.