# Dependency problems after faulty Ubuntu upgrade ( `gcc-5-base` )

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I tried upgrading from 14.02 to the newest available version.
I package froze the installation progress and I was left with a broken system. Many important packages ( including all of the `apt` packages ) where depending on a broken `libc6` and `libstdc++`. After trying to manually reinstalling and recompiling all the libraries depending on those packages have I ended up in the following dependencies hell. 
`# dpkg --configure -a`

```
dpkg: error processing package click (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script was interrupted
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libstdc++6:amd64:
 libstdc++6:amd64 depends on gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-8ubuntu2); however:
  Version of gcc-5-base:amd64 on system is 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04.

dpkg: error processing package libstdc++6:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libstdc++6:i386:
 libstdc++6:i386 depends on gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-8ubuntu2); however:
  Version of gcc-5-base:i386 on system is 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04.

dpkg: error processing package libstdc++6:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-system-settings:
 ubuntu-system-settings depends on libstdc++6 (>= 5.2); however:
  Package libstdc++6:amd64 is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-system-settings depends on click | ubuntu-snappy-cli; however:
  Package click is not configured yet.
  Package ubuntu-snappy-cli is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-system-settings (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-system-settings-online-accounts:
 ubuntu-system-settings-online-accounts depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1); however:
  Package libstdc++6:amd64 is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-system-settings-online-accounts depends on ubuntu-system-settings; however:
  Package ubuntu-system-settings is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-system-settings-online-accounts (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apt-transport-https:
 apt-transport-https depends on libstdc++6 (>= 5.2); however:
  Package libstdc++6:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apt-transport-https (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apt-utils:
 apt-utils depends on libstdc++6 (>= 5.2); however:
  Package libstdc++6:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apt-utils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapt-inst1.7:amd64:
 libapt-inst1.7:amd64 depends on libstdc++6 (>= 5.2); however:
  Package libstdc++6:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libapt-inst1.7:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapt-pkg4.16:amd64:
 libapt-pkg4.16:amd64 depends on libstdc++6 (>= 5.2); however:
  Package libstdc++6:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libapt-pkg4.16:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapt-pkg4.16:i386:
 libapt-pkg4.16:i386 depends on libstdc++6 (>= 5.2); however:
  Package libstdc++6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libapt-pkg4.16:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apt:
 apt depends on libapt-pkg4.16 (>= 1.0.10.2ubuntu1); however:
  Package libapt-pkg4.16:amd64 is not configured yet.
 apt depends on libstdc++6 (>= 5.2); however:
  Package libstdc++6:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
resolvconf: Error: /run/resolvconf/interface either does not exist or is not a directory
dpkg: error processing package resolvconf (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 click
 libstdc++6:amd64
 libstdc++6:i386
 ubuntu-system-settings
 ubuntu-system-settings-online-accounts
 apt-transport-https
 apt-utils
 libapt-inst1.7:amd64
 libapt-pkg4.16:amd64
 libapt-pkg4.16:i386
 apt
 resolvconf
```

`# apt-get -f upgrade`

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapt-inst1.5 : Depends: libapt-pkg4.12 (>= 0.8.16~exp9) but it is not installable
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-8ubuntu2) but 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04 is installed
 libstdc++6:i386 : Depends: gcc-5-base:i386 (= 5.3.1-8ubuntu2) but 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Now I tried to update from `gcc-5-base 5.3.0` to `5.3.1` but then I end up with a lot of broken dependencies for these packages:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lib32gcc1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04) but 5.3.1-8ubuntu2 is installed
 lib32stdc++6 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04) but 5.3.1-8ubuntu2 is installed
 libapt-inst1.5 : Depends: libapt-pkg4.12 (>= 0.8.16~exp9) but it is not installable
 libatomic1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04) but 5.3.1-8ubuntu2 is installed
 libcilkrts5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04) but 5.3.1-8ubuntu2 is installed
 libgcc1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04) but 5.3.1-8ubuntu2 is installed
 libgcc1:i386 : Depends: gcc-5-base:i386 (= 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04) but 5.3.1-8ubuntu2 is installed
 libgfortran3 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04) but 5.3.1-8ubuntu2 is installed
 libgomp1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04) but 5.3.1-8ubuntu2 is installed
 libitm1 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04) but 5.3.1-8ubuntu2 is installed
 liblsan0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04) but 5.3.1-8ubuntu2 is installed
 libquadmath0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04) but 5.3.1-8ubuntu2 is installed
 libtsan0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04) but 5.3.1-8ubuntu2 is installed
 libubsan0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04) but 5.3.1-8ubuntu2 is installed
```

Comment: Do you mean you upgraded from 14.04? In any case, you can't upgrade directly to the latest version. You have to upgrade to every release in between. I recommend reinstalling. http://askubuntu.com/questions/688820/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-15-10

Comment: I updated to latest available, from the standard upgrade command. But there's no way to actually solve this dependency hell, other than reinstalling?

Comment: There is probably a way, but there are other users more competent than me, to outline such a procedure. My gut feeling simply tells me reinstalling would be less of a hassle. Takes maybe 1-2 hours to wipe out the partitions and reinstall. Compare that to the time you have spent fixing your OS and it it's still not fixed. It's your choice, hopefully someone chimes in with a solution, or you can Google your way through this.