# Upgraded Ubuntu 14.04 to a newer version, cannot boot: end Kernal panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!

Tags: 14.04, boot, upgrade, kernel

I've been using Ubuntu 14.04 for a few months now and thought I'd update to a later version. Therefore, I followed this query ([Update Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/618741/update-ubuntu-14-04-to-15-04)) and upgraded.
Oddly enough, when I checked my version in the terminal, it said 16.04... So I'd upgraded to the developer version, instead. Restarted my computer, as per the steps.
However, this appears every time on boot, and I cannot progress:

[http://i.imgur.com/CWXg6r2.gif](https://i.imgur.com/CWXg6r2.gif)

"end Kernal panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!"

I've already looked around for tips how to fix this. Started in safe mode, but I get the same error. I'd rather not reinstall the OS again, as I'd lose many of the preferences of programs I've installed before (Backed up the actual documents etc).

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried booting with an older kernel (enter GRUB menu, Advanced options for Ubuntu, older kernel)?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to boot each of them, safe mode and normal. The same error occurs.

Comment: No, I'm not talking about "normal" or "safe" modes. I'm talking about an old, possibly functional kernel.

Comment: I'm in GRUB. When I go to 'Advanced options for Ubuntu', I get a list. "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.19.0-47-generic and 3.19.0-47-generic (recovery mode) all the way down to 3.19.0-25 generic and the recovery mode. Tried all of them and neither work. Is this what you meant?