# attempted ugrade 14.04 -> 15.10 : /sbin/init/bih/sh: 0: Can’t open splash

Tags: boot, init, fsck

the other day I tried to upgrade my ubuntu 14.04 desktop machine (dual booted with win 10) to ubuntu 15.10. I did `do-release-upgrade` from the command line.

The process went along for about 15 mins, but then it spit out a message saying the process halted because there were too many errors.

I tried to shut down the machine, but it hung. So, I hit the reset switch, got thru BIOS, selected ubuntu from the grub menu and then saw something similar to this:

```
Target filesystem doesn’t have requested /sbin/init/bih/sh: 0: Can’t open splash
kernel panic not syncing: attmpted to kill init! exit code
```

I saw [this q](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17647/target-filesystem-doesnt-have-requested-sbin-init) which says to boot from the live CD and run fsck, but I'm wondering if I was trying to upgrade anyway if it wouldn't be better to just install from the live disk.

Will that overwrite my previous ubuntu install and leave the windows install as is? Also, will booting with a boot repair disk help?

thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/618741/update-ubuntu-14-04-to-15-04)