# Upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade

As I understand it, in order to upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 one must upgrade to 14.10.  At this time it appears 14.10 is not supported.  From the command line `do-release-upgrade -d` produces

```
WARNING:root:file 'utopic.tar.gz.gpg' missing
Failed to fetch
Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.
```

(there is no problem with my network)

Is there a workaround, perhaps a mirror to the official?  I just don't have the time to install 16.04 from scratch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I smoothly upgrade from one LTS to next LTS release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/717827/can-i-smoothly-upgrade-from-one-lts-to-next-lts-release)

Comment: Your understanding is incomplete. 14.04 is LTS (Long Term Support) as is 16.04. Therefore you can upgrade directly from one to the other. Since these are LTS you will not see the upgrade prompt until 16.04.1, the first "point release" comes out in July 21, 2016.

Answer (score 5):

Upgrades from 14.04 to 16.04 are not automatically made available but in July the first point release 16.04.1 will become available and all 14.04 users will be offered the upgrade then.

However, if you want to upgrade immediately, you do NOT need to upgrade to an intermediate release first. Just run the following in a terminal (and type your password):

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

You will then be offered the 14.04 -> 16.04 upgrade without waiting for 16.04.1.

The reason Ubuntu doesn't automatically offer 16.04 to 14.04 users is simple: those users are using a very stable LTS release, and might hit undiscovered bugs in 16.04 if they upgraded immediately at release. Any important bugs found in 16.04 should be fixed by the 16.04.1 point release, so LTS users have less chance of running into bugs in the new release.

Answer (score 2):

By running the normal upgrade commands in 14.04 (    sudo apt-get update,
    sudo apt-get upgrade,
    sudo apt-get dist-upgrade,
    sudo update-manager -d) -

[image]

Canonical responds with the following -

[image]

Selecting "Upgrade" gives -

[image]

By doing the following I was able to upgrade from 14.04 to 14.10

1. Change all instances of http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ in /etc/apt/sources.list to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
2. Run the normal commands: 
   sudo apt-get update,
   sudo apt-get upgrade,
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade,
   sudo update-manager -d
3. Then upgrade from 14.10 to 15.10 and then to 16.04

Comment: Upgrading from 14.10 to 15.10 without going through 15.04 is also not supported.  As The Brown One already pointed out, 16.04 is still not officially released, hence the normal upgrade tool in 14.04 does not yet offer upgrading to it.  If you want to upgrade anyhow, you can just change sources.list to point to wily and run update/dist-upgrade.

Comment: One system I was able to upgrade from 14.10 to 16.04.  Another system I was not able to upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 without first upgrading to 14.10 by the method I outlined above.  I am simply upgrading a few machines to 16.04 beta and just need to get the job done.  And this how you do it (or wait, and I don't wait).

Comment: I found switching the "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" (in the Software & Updates settings) to `For any new version` and back to `For long-term support versions` seemed to trick it into working

Answer (score 1):

According to the [release schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), 16.04 (Xenial Xerus) will be officially released on April 21st, 2016. Until then, there is no officially supported method of upgrade.

If you want to test 16.04, you can always [download the latest beta build](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/) and use the Live CD/Live USB environment.

Comment: I just upgraded one system from 14.10 to 16.04 by upgrading to 15.10 and then to 16.04.  Your response does not answer my question.

Comment: That is the "experimental" release chain. While it may work, it is not officially supported.

Comment: I need to upgrade from 14.04 to 14.10.  The rest is up to me.  Simple question.  Can it be done and if so, how?

Comment: I don't really care what is "officially supported".

Comment: Give me 5 minutes, I'll make another write-up about how to enable the experimental builds in `Software Properties` and update from there.

Comment: Correct but not totally.. 14.04 to 16.04 will be available later than 21st ... it will be 14.04.2 that allows lts to lts upgrades. @brett as we are an official support site we -do- care ;-)

Comment: may have found the solution here - http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release.  What do you think?

Comment: @Rinzwind - did not mean it that way!

Comment: @brett oh I was not seriously serious either ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading from one LTS release directly to the next ( like 14.04 to 16.04 ) is supported; you do not need to go thorugh all of the intervening releases.

Comment: You are incorrect -  read the following:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/618741/update-ubuntu-14-04-to-15-04

Comment: @brett, no sir, I am not.  The question you linked is about upgrading to a NON LTS release.

Comment: see my self answer.  I just ran the upgrade commands on a 14.04 machine and got the response show by screen capture.  If you have an explanation, please share.